# Do visibility declarations affect using (as opposed to compiling) a function?

Tags: c, linux, macos, linker, visibility

**tl;dr** Do GCC's visibility attributes affect only how a function is compiled, or also how it is used?

---

Do [GCC visibility attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) in function declarations, such as `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`, make any difference at all when *using* a function, rather than when compiling a function?

Of course, these attributes affect compiling the function. My question concerns only the case of using / calling / linking to a function:

```
extern VISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE int foo(int x);

void myfun() { foo(); }
```

Assume that `foo()` has already been compiled and is present in either a shared or a static library.

My question concerns Linux and macOS, not Windows.

Is it correct that the visibility is encoded in the object file output by the compiler, and after the object file has already been produced, the visibility declaration is no longer used for anything by the compiler?  In particular, it is irrelevant for calling the function?

Comment: With these types of questions it's often best to simply try it out. Create a program that declares and uses two functions one with visibility "default" and one with "hidden". Then use utilities like `readelf` and `nm` to inspect the binary.

Comment: @asynts In fact I did try before asking, and could not see any effect of the visibility declarations. But not all such empirical findings generalize. It's better to have some understanding of how this works.

Comment: I guess I was a bit rash there, the visibility really isn't something that is easily observable.  [This blog entry](https://www.airs.com/blog/archives/307) touches on that, but it goes a bit off topic, should provide a bit of context though. When talking about symbols and all that stuff, it generally makes sense to look at a [`elf(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) man page. If you take these things together, you should have a good idea what happens.